# Do i need to create a new activity for every game level?

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have a game where you answer questions. Every level the questions get harder and harder and to open a new level you need to answer a specific amount of questions in the previous level. Do I need to create a new activity with each level and its own questions? If I have 100+ levels I will need 100 activities? Wont that lag the app? Maybe there is another way? I always wondered how games like candy crush manage that amount of levels?

Comment: No, you can use fragment and reused it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fragment, and everytime you change the level you can replace it.
First of all you have to read the [FragmentTransaction examplanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html), and then replace the fragment you are if you change the level...

An easy example of replace will be :

```
Fragment NextLevel= new NextLevel();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, NextLevel);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

It is how I would do this If I had to do this, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way i'd do it is the following:

1x Activity to simply hold the fragments
1x Fragment, which receives (in constructor for example) the data it needs (in this case, your questions, the answers to the questions, etc etc), and then simply displays it.
Then when the user needs to change to another question level, simply instansiate another fragment and give it the new information it needs to show, and then close down the old fragment.

In the end you'll have 1 fragment, but it'll be instantiated many times.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dynamic and multi-pane user interface on Android, like you said, a lot of levels, you need to encapsulate UI components and activity behaviors into modules that you can swap into and out of your activities.

You can create these modules with the `Fragment` class, which behaves somewhat like a nested activity that can define its own layout and manage its own lifecycle.

Then there's no need for 100 activities.

You can refer to this official example from Android Developers to get started

> http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/FragmentBasics.zip

Best of luck!